# Twig namespaced path without slash works on local machine (Mac) but not on the server

Tags: symfony, namespaces, twig

I am working on a legacy project from 2013 (once Symfony 2 but now Symfony 3.4) and when I try to get a Twig file (which resides multiple directories down) with this path:

```
'MyBundle:Default:_partials:internalSubStatus.html.twig'
```

This works fine on my local machine (Mac) but gives an error on the server

> "Unable to find template
>   "MyBundle:Default:_partials:internalSubStatus.html.twig" (looked into:
>   /var/www/mylocalpathhere/htdocs/app/Resources/views,
>   /var/www/mylocalpathhere/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form)."

It only happens when there are multiple folders. So it works without a slash when it is only one folder deep like this

```
'MyBundle:_partials:internalSubStatus.html.twig'
```

In multiple folders deep we always need one slash.
So it **does work** in following cases *by replacing 1 colon with a slash*. Why is this? And what is the way to go?

```
MyBundle:Default:_partials/internalSubStatus.html.twig

MyBundle:Default/_partials:internalSubStatus.html.twig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MyBundle:Default:_partials:internalSubStatus.html.twig` is the old syntax an no longer recommended. `/` works because the resolver will now look for a subdirectory. This is confusing, and [an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/3849) has been created in 2014 about your very question.

The way to go is to use the new syntax which you can also find in the [documentary for symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle), and I quote:

> If you need to refer to a template that lives in a bundle, Symfony
>   uses the Twig namespaced syntax
>   (@BundleName/directory/filename.html.twig). This allows for several
>   types of templates, each which lives in a specific location

In your case I immagine that would be `@MyBundle/Default/_partials/internalSubStatus.html.twig`

Comment: Thank you for clearing it out! It is an old legacy project and for the sake of not mixing too much different coding styles in one project I kept on doing it like they did in the past. And it still worked on my local machine. That's what made it confusing.